# What is the difference between First and FirstOrDefault , Last and LastOrDefault

Tags: linq

i am working with **LINQ** there i use First and FirstOrDefault both return the same result what is the difference

Comment: have a look at to [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/329/first-firstordefault-last-lastordefault-single-and-singleordefault#t=201609220738336033875)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and Last throw an exception if no result was found.
FirstOrDefault and LastOrDefault return the result variable type's default value in that case.

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault and LastOrDefault would not throw an exception if there are no search item in sequence, they will return null.

Comment: Not exactly. They only return null if null is the return type's default value. In case of an integer, they return 0, etc.

Comment: Ah, if you u wont. They return **variable type`s default value**.